# Fix Python Guessing Game to not count erroneous tries

Tags: python

Running Python code for guessing game - if guess number outside of range - do not want it to count against tries. Code works but counts erroneous numbers as tries.

**My code:**

```
import random

print("The number is between 1 and 10")
print("You have 5 tries!")

theNumber = random.randrange(1,10)
maxTries = 5
tries = 1
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))


while ((tries < maxTries) & (guess != theNumber)):  
    try:                    
        if guess > theNumber:
            print("Guess lower...")
        elif guess < theNumber:
            print("Guess higher...")        
        if guess > 10:
                raise ValueError

    except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a numeric value between 1 and 10.")
            #continue

    guess = int(input("Guess again: "))
    tries = tries + 1


    if(guess == theNumber):
        print("You guessed it! The number was", theNumber)
        print("And it only took you", tries, "tries!\n")
    else:
        print("You failed to guess", theNumber, "!")
```

It allows continued guessing up to 5 tries as long as guess is between 1 and 10. If outside of this range - it will not count as a try but tells the user to "Please enter a numeric value between 1 and 10"). Which the code does - it just counts those tries when I do not want it to work that way.

Comment: Please fix your formatting so the indentation levels are clear, but it looks like you increment tries in every case. You'll need to include that in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
import random

min_number = 1
max_number = 10
number = random.randrange(min_number, max_number + 1)
print(number) # To know the number you are guessing
maximum_tries = 5

print(f"The number is between {min_number} and {max_number}")
print(f"You have {maximum_tries} tries!")

guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

j = 1

while True:

    if guess > max_number or guess < min_number:
        print("Please enter a numeric value between 1 and 10.")
        j = j - 1
    elif guess > number:
        print("Guess lower...")
        print("You failed to guess", j, "!")
    elif guess < number:
        print("Guess higher...")
        print("You failed to guess", j, "!")

    if guess == number:
        print("You guessed it! The number was", number)
        print("And it only took you", j, "tries!\n")
        break

    if j == maximum_tries:
        break

    guess = int(input("Guess again: "))
    j = j + 1
```